# Issue with Windows impersonation in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, impersonation

Web-application is running on my local PC (which is not in any domain) under IIS, and its **web.config** file contains the following:

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN01\user01" password="password" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

**DOMAIN01\user01** is my account in domain **DOMAIN01**.

I can open shared folders on computers in the domain **DOMAIN01**

But when I'm running the application I get this error:

> Server Error in '/app' Application.
> Description: An error occurred
> during the processing of a configuration file required to service this
> request. Please review the specific error details below and modify
> your configuration file appropriately.
> Parser Error Message: Could not
> create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config
> file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is
> incorrect.'

If I change **userName** and **password** in **web.config** to the local user there is no error. So application can't login as **DOMAIN01\user01**

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: When use the identity of DOMAIN01\user01, application pool is DOMAIN01\user01. Are you sure that this user have the read and write permission to shared folder? It is best to set the permission to full control.

Comment: @bruce-zhang I can't assign the user DOMAIN01\user01 any permissions, because my local PC doesn't see this user in the permissions dialog.
And also I can't add that user to any local group.
Actually, I think it's even not possible to fix the problem in my question.
I'm going to fix it other way.